Random Variables that are pairwise independent but not mutually independent
Given more than two events, (for example) $A,B,C \subset \Omega$  we know that these events can be pairwise independent without being mutually independent.
Is this the same for random variables?
(I do assume so, everything else would be very surprising.)
For that reason I tried to come up with a example.
Let $\Omega=\{A,B,C,D\}$, $\mathcal{F}:=2^{\Omega}$, $P(S):=1/4$ for $S \in \Omega$.
As far as I know the independence random variables $X_1,X_2$ are independent, if $\sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2)$ are independent. This meaning that for every $F_1 \in \sigma(X_1) $and $G_1 \in \sigma(X_2)$, we have $P(F_1 \cap G_1)=P(F_1)P(G_1)$.
When we only consider events, one can see that $E_1:=\{A,B\}$,$E_2:=\{B,C\}$,$E_3:=\{A,C\}$ are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.
Now a random variable is a map $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. How can I define random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ such that they are pairwise independent but not mutually independent?

Try out the indicator functions of the events.

Continuous Example :
Let the three random variables $X,Y,Z$ generate three real numbers $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=0$
Knowing one ( Eg $x$ ) gives no information about the other two ( $y$ , $z$ )
Knowing two ( Eg $x$ & $y$ ) makes the other ( $z$ ) automatically known.
These random variables are "Pairwise Independent" without being "Mutually Independent".
We can extend this to more variables.
Discrete Example :
Consider the Single-Digit Decimal numbers $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
Let the three random variables $X,Y,Z$ generate three such Digits $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z \bmod 9 \equiv 0$
Always , knowing one ( Eg $x$ ) gives almost no information about the other two ( $y$ , $z$ )
Sometimes , knowing two ( Eg $x=2$ & $y=3$ ) makes the other ( $z=4$ ) automatically known.
Sometimes , knowing two ( Eg $x=6$ & $y=3$ ) lets the other ( $z$ might be $\{0,9\}$ ) get a little restricted.
These random variables are "Pairwise Independent" without being "Mutually Independent".
We can extend like-wise this to more variables.

For any three events, $A,B,C$ which are pairwise independent but not independent, defined random variables $X=1_A$, $Y=1_B$, $Z=1_C$. Then $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent but not independent.
(An easiest example is, perhaps, the following. You toss a fair coin twice, and let $A=$"the first one is Head", $B=$"the second one is Head", $C=$"the outcomes of the two tosses are the same".)
